# Cambiar ruta de la carpeta Vendor (de notificaciones) en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con la personalización del correo electrónico para restablecer la contraseña con Auth de laravel, con el siguiente comando: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications la carpeta vendor se guarda en la siguiente ruta: resources/views/vendor y deseo guardarla en  resources/views/OTRO_DIRECTORIO/vendor cómo puedo hacer que lo lea allí, ya que copiando y pegando el directorio no funciona, me imagino que debo cambiar la ruta en elgún lugar, o generar un nuevo archivo con composer pero no se como asignarle esa ruta. Gracias